# How will we handle spoiler alerts?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we behave with questions/answers that reveal spoiler?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-behave-with-questions-answers-that-reveal-spoiler)

I am truly hoping that we will become a large community of gamers that are happy to share knowledge amongst their peers.  I have one worry in regards to game story spoilers.  I would hate to jump into someone's question and find out they are asking, for example, "How do I beat *insert bad guy's name here* at the end of *insert final stage location here*?" for a game that I'm currently playing or want to play in the future.

I know the Stack Exchange system doesn't really have built in measures for this, but hopefully we can enforce both of the following:

1. All question titles that contain spoiler information begin the question with **Spoiler:**
2. Tag all questions with a *spoiler* tag

What are people's thoughts on this?